# How to get shell output from current time stamp. Linux, unix

Tags: android, linux, shell, unix, adb

in many shell commands the output is a continuous stream of events, such as system log. I need to view only the outputs from now or current system time. 
here is a program output I get from adb logcat,

```
09-03 17:12:04.562   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity } from pid 1230
09-03 17:12:04.687   479  1030 I ActivityManager: Start proc com.amazon.mShop.android for activity com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity: pid=19164 uid=10158 gids={1006, 3003}
09-03 17:12:05.593   479   912 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat=?paramSuggestionText=cell%20phone flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 17:12:05.796   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +186ms (total +1s119ms)
09-03 17:12:08.601   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity: +3s925ms
09-03 17:12:08.601   479   620 I ActivityManager: Resumed Activity: com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity totalTime: 4037 ms
09-03 17:13:35.742   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=intentActionStartActivity flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity } from pid 19164
09-03 17:13:36.007   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.categoryBrowse.CategoryBrowseActivity: +222ms
09-03 17:13:53.328   479   957 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { dat=?&paramSuggestionFilters=s%3An%3A%2C%3A4991425011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A4991426011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A5088769011%0As%3An%3A%2C%3A5263615011&paramDepartmentName=Programs flg=0x20000 cmp=com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity (has extras) } from pid 19164
09-03 17:13:53.484   479   620 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.search.SearchActivity: +145ms
```

It is a continuous stream, that is showing events from the system start, but I only need the logs that are from current system time. So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "from current system time"? Does it mean a range, starting with a certain ("current") time, never ending? How do you define "current" time? A time when some kind of command was executed?

Comment: @GreyCat i mean only the output that is from the time the command is issued will be needed. but some commands like android adb logcat shows all the logs from the system start, i dont need that, i only need the log that is from the time i issued the command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved with logcat -c option. a more general solution is using tail -f command line option. though it is not super accurate but works.

Answer (score 1):

According to [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) manual, it's possible to do this in two steps:

1. Clear the log using `logcat -c`
2. Proceed with continuous log monitoring using regular `logcat` call

If this ought to be combined together, I guess just running `logcat -c && logcat` will be the solution.

Comment: yes this solution worked for the particular problem I have. A general solution may be using tail -f though this is not super accurate.